# drools working with dates

Tags: drools, rules, java.util.date

In official documentation I can't find any information how to write conditional statements for java.util.Date type fact fields in guided rules. For example how to compare such field to current date, check if it is equal omitting time, or check if it is date before some time from now?

Answer (score 0):

Drools isn't a real-time program and it doesn't have an innate idea of Time or Now. If you need to investigate relations of some fact property w.r.t. some point of time X, you'll have to establish a fact carrying X as its data, and write your rules based on that.

A more or less coarse approximation of a fact representing Now can be made using timers. You can implement a rule that modifies a fact containing a value representing Time (e.g. java.util.Date) every second, or less frequently.

Blending out the time of the day is something you'll have to do using Java or DRL functions. Alternatively, if it is days you are interested in, use some custom class representing days, with some suitable day 1 defined by you.

Answer (score 0):

you can give like

```
 inputDate>=11-Nov-2014
 provide your current date to inputDate rule input Fact variable.
```